# Voxelize VFX and Particles

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, effects

**I'm creating a voxel Unity Game, and i want to know if i can i voxelize vfx and/or particles?**
*for example: voxelize a explosion effect, and create a voxel explosion*

**Video Examples:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDzT6ZJyIcw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSSDp5f6L7k
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1v4r4JQSQg (my favorite)

Thanks Anyway,
Emanuel Messias

Comment: While I understand the confusion, this question is more about the capabilities of Unity than Blender.  Nothing is stopping you from modeling voxel-ey things in Blender, but particles are handled entirely by Unity.

Comment: you could put it on gamedev.stackexchange, that's a good place to put unity questions. :)